# BluetoothGatt Object is Busy

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing an application using BluetoothGatt class and API for android devices. Application has a feature where user can disconnect one device and connect with another bluetooth device. Basically user can add or remove devices in the app.

To achieve this when user adds a new BLE device i use the same BluetoothGatt object to first disconnect the old device and than connect the new device.

Connection happens nicely but when i start reading characteristics of that device most of the time i get an error something like No Connection for "Bluetooth Address". And when i inspected the BluetoothGatt object is status is Busy.

I am really clueless on what wrong i am doing , can any body help me to understand what wrong i am doing.

Just to mention if i use only one device than everything is working fine.

Comment: Can you show logcat output giving that error message?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply but this is error i am getting :                     11-24 17:40:45.275 11426-11442/? E/BluetoothRemoteDevices: state12newState0
11-24 17:41:02.421 11426-11442/? E/BluetoothRemoteDevices: state12newState1
11-24 17:41:15.110 11426-11442/? E/BluetoothRemoteDevices: state12newState0
11-24 17:41:15.549 11426-11460/? E/BtGatt.GattService: readCharacteristic() - No connection for deviceAddress

Comment: Seems to be some internal error in Android's bluetooth. Can you show your code?

Comment: I was able to come over this problem please check my answer !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this problem, i was using a service to initialize , connect gatt client object , and also the same service for processing data received from gatt client.

So intead of disconnecting and connecting the gatt client again , i unbinded the service , which made sure the gatt client is disconnected and closed. For new device connection i created a new service.

This is now working fine !!